# jQuery with lots of 'if' statements. there must be a neater way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, if-statement

I have written a function that will scroll my page to the nearest defined point (the top of a layer) after the user scrolls.

I am incredibly pleased with myself but I look at the code and it just looks clunky and orrible. Without much further ado:

```
enter code here

sli1 = 0;
sli2 = slideheight;
sli3 = (slideheight * 2);
sli4 = (slideheight * 3);
sli5 = (slideheight * 4);
sli6 = (slideheight * 5);
sli7 = (slideheight * 6);
frac = (slideheight / 2);

function autoScroll() {
    cl = mywindow.scrollTop();
    if(cl < sli2-frac && cl < sli1+frac){goToByScroll(1);}
    if(cl > sli2-frac && cl < sli2+frac){goToByScroll(2);}
    if(cl > sli3-frac && cl < sli3+frac){goToByScroll(3);}
    if(cl > sli4-frac && cl < sli4+frac){goToByScroll(4);}
    if(cl > sli5-frac && cl < sli5+frac){goToByScroll(5);}
    if(cl > sli6-frac && cl < sli6+frac){goToByScroll(6);}
    if(cl > sli7-frac && cl < sli7+frac){goToByScroll(7);}
}
```

I think it should look more like this...

```
function aS() {
/*loop to create array like 
array = ('sl[0] = 0', sl[1] = sh.... there must be a way of automating this part*\
     cL = mW.scrollTop();
     var cH = (cl < sl[1]-f && cl < sl[0]+f)?'1':(cl > sl[1]-f && cl < sl[1]+f)?'2':
     (cl > sl[2]-f && cl < sl[2]+f)?'3':(cl > sl[3]-f && cl < sl[3]+f)?'4':
     (cl > sl[4]-f && cl < sl[4]+f)?'5':(cl > sl[5]-f && cl < sl[5]+f)?'6':
     (cl > sl[6]-f && cl < sl[6]+f)?'7'goToByScroll(cH);
```

But now looking at that that even looks ugly, is there a way of doing it nicely with some kind of genius logic. I hope that I'm making sense here, the code works but I think it can be done in a more elegant way but I'm new to jQuery it is fun though I have hit a brick wall on this one now, please help me.

My solution, is javascript perhaps but the .js file starts:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

and the  is goToByScroll() function is jQuery....

```
 function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
htmlbody.animate({
    scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
}, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
 }
```

Comment: What the heck does this have anything to do with jQuery?

Comment: @Christian scrollTop() is a jQuery method. That is the only thing I see.

Comment: Yeah, and just about 90% of the code is plain javascript....

Comment: @Christian If it's that big of a problem, edit the question and remove the tag. There's no need for the attitude, especially to a newbie.

Comment: Yes there is, users are expected to know the problem they're trying to tackle. If they don't know common programming constructs (loops etc) from libraries, something's wrong.

Comment: @SuperKim Let me repeat this one last time. If you can't see the difference between a programming construct (if statements, loops, functions) and a javascript framework, then please, rethink what you're doing. jQuery doesn't magically have a solution to every small specific issue you might come up with, and even if it did, it would be a waste of effort since it's a relatively simple mathematical calculation.

Comment: @Christian Thank you for your input, perhaps I used the wrong tag but I can see the difference in a useful response and a pointless response, I wish you could have done that before posting yours. Anyone reading this is wasting their time and that is not the point of this website, it should be to help people and is not the place for you to release your pent up aggression.

Comment: And yet you do not understand my point. It would have been easier for everyone if you corrected the question instead of arguing...and wasting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps something like

```
function autoScroll() {
    var cl = mywindow.scrollTop(),
        target = Math.floor((cl / slideheight)+0.4999) + 1 || 1;

    goToByScroll( target );
}
```

Comment: I was about to post the same. The `frac` is then irrelevant.

Comment: I've tested this but it doesn't function correctly, the page will slide up to the top slide from the third and sometimes it goes up two, also the point that it chooses is different on each slide, hmm it is a nice idea though I think the maths doesn't work the same.

Comment: @SuperKim, you are correct.. the math was off .. i have corrected it.

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli, Yea now it works just right :) It is exactly what I was looking for, a much neater way to solve the problem. Also this way allows for additional slides without having to update the .js file. Thank you!